# Django - Select from a list

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list :

```
logo_nofav = [('codwaw.png', 'codwaw'), ('lol.png', 'lol')]
```

In my template I can :

- call the first in the list with `{{logo_nofav.0}}`
- call the second with `{{logo_nofav.1}}`
- just call the second element of the second in the list with `{{logo_nofav.1.1}}`

Now my question is, how could I just call the second element of each object.
We could image `{{logo_nofav.x.1}}` where "x" is a variable which means anywhere on the list.

I hop I was clear. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate through the list,

```
{% for item in logo_nofav %}
{{ item.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```